# Can I map multiple domain accounts (or authentication sources) to one user/profile?

Tags: 2010, user-profile, authentication, my-site

This is probably impossible but...

We have a local 2010 farm and HQ has one.  I've been asked to use the HQ MySites service application rather than doing our own, which is very sensible.

However, on our local farm we're using a local domain: UNDPNT, when we go to the HQ intranet we're using our UNDPCO credentials.

What's the scope for the HQ farm's MySites application recognizing that a user logged into our local domain as being a matching member on its domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be resolved using domain trusts and publishing the user profile app on the HQ farm and consuming it on your farm. 
The trust between the 2 domains can be 1 way if needed, but that does require some extra configuration. a 2 way trust sharepoint resolves automatically.

Another option is using ForeFrfont Identity Manager and importing your users as Foreign Security Principals into the HQ domain.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the answer I'm looking for.  That is "Yes, we can do it but it's very complicated and requires new software," which should give me the necessary ammunition to kill the idea and not have to work over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to have trust relationships between the domains and have just the one account per employee?

In order to get a multiple user occupancy MySite functionality on 2007 took a lot of custom code (not using MySites at all).  I'd keep it simple if I were you.

Comment: Yes, already investigated that.  The chances of us getting a 2-way trust to the HQ (worldwide) AD are vanishingly small.  I guess we're not very trustworthy.